# Python: How to read one element first and followed by two elements?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, binary

I would like to scan through sequences and return the value either 1 or 0 to indicate whether they are present or absent. For example: XYZXYZ

```
X Y Z X Y Z 
1 0 0 1 0 0 - X
0 1 0 0 1 0 - Y
0 0 1 0 0 1 - Z
0 0 0 0 0 0 - XX
1 1 0 1 1 0 - XY
0 0 0 0 0 0 - XZ
0 0 0 0 0 0 - YX
0 0 0 0 0 0 - YY
0 1 1 0 1 1 - YZ
0 0 1 1 0 1 - ZX
0 0 0 0 0 0 - ZY
0 0 0 0 0 0 - ZZ
```

For two elements like XY, while scanning two elements at position X it will be given value one and when scanning at position Y, it will be given value one as well.

The example code below only scans one element at a time. When I replaced this line of code,

```
CHARS = ['X','Y','Z']
```

to

```
CHARS = ['X','Y','Z','XX','XY','XZ',...,'ZZ']
```

It can't read two elements.

The code below returns binary values in one line starting from X first and then Y and then followed by Z.

```
import numpy as np
seqs = ["XYZXYZ","YZYZYZ"]
CHARS = ['X','Y','Z']
CHARS_COUNT = len(CHARS)
maxlen = max(map(len, seqs))
res = np.zeros((len(seqs), CHARS_COUNT * maxlen), dtype=np.uint8)

for si, seq in enumerate(seqs):
    seqlen = len(seq)
    arr = np.chararray((seqlen,), buffer=seq)
    for ii, char in enumerate(CHARS):
        res[si][ii*seqlen:(ii+1)*seqlen][arr == char] = 1

print res
```

Example output of the code above:

> [[1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
>    [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]]

How to enable it scan one element first and then followed by two elements?

Expected output:

```
[[1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely get all the details, but this is what I'd do

```
seqs = ['xyzxyz', 'yzyzyz']
chars = ['x','y','z','xx','xy','xz','yx','yy','yz','zx','zy','zz']

N = len(chars)
out = []
for i, seq in enumerate(seqs):
    M = len(seq)  # if different seqs have different lenghts, this will break!
    tmp = np.array([], dtype=int)
    for c in chars:
        o = np.array([0]*M)
        index = -1
        try:
            while True:
                index = seq.index(c, index+1)
                o[index:(index+len(c))] = 1
        except ValueError:
            pass
        finally:
            tmp = np.r_[tmp, o]
    out.append(tmp)
out = np.array(out)
```